C++ Builder 12.2 Style not found after upgrading from 10.4
We have upgraded a larger project from C++Builder 10.4 to 12.2. The project allows to select a UI style from a predefined list, which will be loaded at startup using TStyleManager::SetStyle(STYLENAME);
After migration, the project still compiles fine, but when launching it I get an error:

"Windows10 Dark" (or any other style) not found

The missing Style is included through the project settings ( Project->Options->Application->Appearance ) and this worked fine with the previous version. Manually adding the style files to the project resources does work, but results in visual artifacts in the UI.
